# Which interaction should be preferred for refreshing an individual card in a listview in android app?

Tags: interaction-design, android, ux-field, ux-designer, swipe

I have a listview showing a set of results in android app. I need to refresh the state indicated on the right end of an individual result card in the list. 
I thought of one possible interaction like this: on left pulling of the card, the state of the card(indicated on right end) would be updated.

Are there any better interactions possible to refresh state on individual card ?

Comment: A mockup would be helpful. But in my mind, left/right pulling a card in a list in material design (I assume, talking cards & android) is an action for "removing" the card from the list. Is there space for a simple refresh icon?

Comment: Isn't it pretty standard to refresh results by pulling down from the top of the screen?

Comment: @EricStoltz Pull down to refresh brings in new cards into the viewport, or adds new items to the list. Updating a list item with pull down to refresh is not a desired action. I guess, adding a small refresh icon to the list item would do the job, but that is constrained by the available space in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible for you to design the cards so that they update automatically? That would be the ideal interaction.

If not, I'd recommend using a button instead of a gesture, if simply because swiping is generally used for archiving or removing. Consider how often refresh will be used -- gestures are generally used for things that people need to do very frequently, whereas buttons are suitable for both frequent and infrequent things.

If you still want to go for a gesture, make sure it's discoverable. If there is no clearcut indication that one should pull the card, people won't pull on it. A tutorial might not suffice here -- a person may use your app once, then forget the gesture, then return to your app.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend let the system handle this situation (state update) rather than human being. We need to segregate the responsibilities between system and humans while designing any apps to improve the UX and reduce the cognitive load / process of human being.

In my opinion, if the state is not modified by the user, the system should take of it and auto-refresh it (not whole screen / page, just a required segment)